# Unescpaing huge single-line string on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I ended up with a huge, single line string literal (don't ask me how) where everything is escaped (mostly), including new lines and double quotes. Problem is, I want the original string. The string is *huge* so I'm not even sure how to begin. Here's what I have:

```
"This\n is \"nice\",\nain\'t it?"
```

This is what I want:

```
This
 is "nice",
ain't it?
```

Again, the problem is that other shell sensitive stuff is *not* escaped (like $, or !), and that the string is couple of megabytes.

Comment: This isn't for DNA splicing, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python one-liner:

```
open("unescaped.txt", "w").write(eval(open("string.txt").read()))
```

You should have python on most linux installs.

Answer (score 2):

```
string="This\n is \"nice\",\nain\'t it?"
string=$(printf "$string")
```

Or

```
string=$(<file.txt)
string=$(printf "$string")
```

Comment: Won't work because the string is not shell escaped and is full of characters like '$' and '!' that will mess up the assignment to a variable. (The first thing I tried, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Sed's your buddy.

```
cat huge | sed -e 's/\\n/\  << yes,hit the enter key here, the \ capture the newline
/g' -e 's/\\"/"/g' -e 's/\\'/'/g' ... > file
```